# Laravel Response::json() with numeric check

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

When performing an eloquent query on a model (using the MySQL driver) which has some numeric fields and then return a json response of the results, the json appears to pass numeric values as strings rather than numbers.

E.g.

```
$properties = Model::find(6);
return Response::json($properties);
```

Returns something like:

```
{
    "name": "A nice item",
    "value": "160806.32"
}
```

When it should return:

```
{
    "name": "A nice item",
    "value": 160806.32
}
```

In normal php you can use the [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-numeric-check) to solve this but there appears to be no such option for the `Response::json()` method. How can I ensure numeric fields are returned as numbers rather than strings?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can actually pass that option over. If we take a look at the source code for the [JsonResponse class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L24) you can pass json_encode options as the last parameter.

It would look something like this

```
return Response::json($properties, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**Alternatively** you could do this:

```
    return Response::make(
        $properties->toJson(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), 
        200, 
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
    );
```

Note: if `$properties` is not an Elequoent model then it must at least implement the [JsonableInterface](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Contracts/JsonableInterface.php#L11)

**as well as**:

```
    return Response::make(
        json_encode($properties->toArray(), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), 
        200, 
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
    );
```

The [toJson()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2121) method in Eloquent just wraps `json_encode()` and passes it the array of your model. I'd recommend using one of the first two options.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example?

Comment: @harryg Added a few examples of how to achieve this :).

Comment: Thanks, the `Response::make` examples are slightly imperfect as the response lacks the json headers and just has the default html headers. Otherwise, seems to work, thanks.

Comment: @harryg Good point :). I also noticed my last example was missing the `toArray()`.

Comment: It's 2018 now but.. be careful when using this flag. If you have strings like "004004004" in your database (a phone number for example), the json response will parse it as "4004004".

Answer (score 11):

Use method `setEncodingOptions` of `JsonResponse`:

```
return response()->json($properties)->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!